# Rails 5 with Apartment - ArgumentError: prepare called on a closed database: rollback transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I've just added the Apartment gem to my existing project to make it a multi tenant application.
after scaffolding a new model named Subdomain, with a single parameter 'title', for each user to enter his name and use the app independently of others, when I try to create a new subdomain on the 'new' page in the browser, I get the following error:

> ArgumentError: prepare called on a closed database: rollback transaction

Extracted source (around line #30): (from the create method of my subdomains_controller.rb)

```
respond_to do |format|
  **if @subdomain.save**  <-- this is line #30, highlighted in the browser
    format.html { redirect_to @subdomain, notice: 'Subdomain was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @subdomain }
  else
```

My Subdomain Model:

```
class Subdomain < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :create_tenant

  private

  def create_tenant
    Apartment::Tenant.create(title)
  end
end
```

I followed the steps to install from [here](https://github.com/influitive/apartment).

I'm pretty new to rails so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from `sqlite3` to `pg`/postgresql worked for me